# No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql - executable java jar

Tags: java, maven

When I run the project as a java application in eclipse it works perfectly but running a `java -jar` on windows cmd throws the SQL exception (No suitable driver found)

I have used maven(maven-assembly) to create the executable jar, a jar-with-dependencies is created in project\target.
The postgresql jar (postgresql-42.2.5.jar) exists in the project\lib folder.

```
 <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.project.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After running `mvn clean package` : 
A manifest file (`project\src\main\resources\MANIFEST.mf`) is copied into `project\target\classes folder`. The manifest file contains Class-Path: `lib/postgresql-42.2.5.jar`.

I have added the dependency in my pom.xml as well.

```
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
     <version>${postgres.driver.version}</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

I was hoping that the Class-Path in manifest file would take care of this issue but it did not.

Might be a duplicate post but none of the existing solutions fixed my problem.

Comment: Did you add the dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: @Vishal yes I did, Updating the question description with the pom dependency

Comment: May be this help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58761760/include-jdbc-driver-for-postgres-in-the-jar-fo-my-simple-demo-app-driven-by-mave

Comment: @BonumUrsus thanks, i've used maven-assembly plugin which should've added the dependencies

Comment: @BonumUrsus changing it to maven-shade did work for me, thanks!